# Grails and JPA integration

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, jpa

I'm trying to integrate a Java domain and service layer with a Grails app. The Java projects are built with Maven and the Grails project loads the JARs from the Maven repo. The service project contains an XML Spring config file, that defines a bunch of Spring beans. I'm trying to make these available to the Grails app, by loading these beans in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
beans = {    
    importBeans('classpath:/applicationContext-services.xml')
}
```

One of the beans in this file is an instance of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. On attempting to create this bean, I get the error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [applicationContext-services.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

Based on [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6705) in Spring's JIRA, it would appear that the underlyiing problem is some incompatibility between the Spring and Hibernate/JPA versions. It appears that I'm using:

- Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate 3.6.0.Final
- Hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.Final

I tried removing the Hibernate plugin from the Grails app, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and had to use downgrade my jpa resources to hibernate 3.3.2.  [Grails 2.0](http://www.grails.org/Roadmap) will have hibernate 3.6 support.

Comment: thanks, do I need to downgrade the Hibernate and Hibernate-JPA JARs or just the former?

Comment: I'm not positive but i'm sure you'll have to use the hibernate-entitymanager instead of the jpa-2.0 reference.  You'll also have to add a few more hibernate references because the older versions had split things out like the validator and annotations.  Kind of a pain :(

Comment: I don't suppose you have any more specific info about the changes necessary?

Comment: I tried using the latest snapshot/milestone for 2.0/1.4 and this problem no longer occurs

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your pom.xml or 'lib' folder:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have likely other jar(s) that define(s) `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo`
get rid of those. Make sure only `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar` is in class path.